# Group your tabs feature Firefox: Automatically sort by domain?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I'm using Firefox 8.0 and am enjoying the Group your tabs feature:

[image]

But I'm not always good at keeping it organized. I'm trying to find a way to automatically put certain domains in certain groups. Probably through a plug-in? All the tab related plug-ins just help cluster your tabs together and don't actually work with the "Group your tabs" feature (which is why I posted the picture, to avoid ambiguity, since grouping tabs can refer to a lot of things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firefox addon *[Mozilla Labs: Prospector - Tab Focus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prospector-tab-focus/)* doesn't exactly do that, but it's the closest I know from what you wish to accomplish. Be aware this an experimental addon.

> An addon that reduces tab clutter by extracting your current browsing session into a new Panorama group.

You may want to vote on [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=629184) which would help you or file a new bug requesting a way to sort by domain.

Answer (score 1):

The [AutoGroup](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autogroup/) addon groups tabs by URL or title. But you still have to specify the patterns (text or regex) by which to group them. It doesn't group tabs by domain unless you specify the domain/s.